# Moving from label into xmm# using movdqa gives me unhandles exception

Tags: c++, assembly, 64-bit

I am just messing around with some registers for the hell of it.

But, I am confused why I keep getting an error here:

`movdqa xmm1, [src]; // Unhandled exception; PS: src is a const void*`

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, because `src` is an address that is not divisible by 16, and `movdqa` is for loads/stores on *aligned* memory addresses.

Comment: what is the appropriate for unaligned then?

Comment: That would be `movdqu`.

Comment: One more question...how can I move directly from xmm into a memory location instead of moving to [esi] i.e. `movdqa [dst], xmm1`?